# Emacs regexp frustration

Tags: regex, emacs

Can someone please explain why this Emacs regexp

```
find_class \(\w+|([^)]+)\) \(\w+|([^)]+)\)
```

does not match in any of these lines?

```
let _, scn, _ = find_class (obj :: cs) c in scn

aux (find_class (obj :: cs) scn) (cn :: desc)

let _, scn, ms = find_class c cs in
```

It seems pretty simple: I'm looking for an invocation of the function where the arguments can appear as single words, or parenthesized arbirary strings. When I plug an equivalent expression (`find_class (\w+|\([^)]+\)) (\w+|\([^)]+\))`) into Ruby it does what I want, but not here. Am I missing something?

I'm finding Emacs' regexps really cumbersome for practical use, to the point where I'm reconsidering my choice of editor. If there is a reasonable way to improve this (i.e. more concise syntax, more character classes), I am dying to hear it, but I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: Ah, when in doubt, slash, slash, slash. It wasn't that, I had to escape the `|` :/. Still, my question remains: isn't there a way to get around the escapes? Escape them, so to speak?

Comment: Not really escape everything when it doubt - it's better to clear the doubt: while `|`, `(`, `{`, `}`, `)` need escape to gain special meaning, `[` and `]` must be without slash to have special meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need `\|` in emacs regex to achieve same effect as `|` in Ruby.

Comment: That's it. But is there any way around all the escaping? When I'm editing, conciseness is a high priority. Is this somehow Lisp's fault?

Comment: @roysc: It's part of the syntax. I don't know why exactly, but this kind of "escaped" regular expression is also observed in `sed`.

Comment: So I've noticed. Maybe the easiest solution is an interactive function to convert a custom syntax to native regexp's. Surely there are tools like that out there.

Comment: Try `M-x regexp-builder`: this will allow you to type in your regexp in a small buffer and highlight all matches in the original buffer on the fly.

Comment: You can also mitigate the string-level escaping in `re-builder` by using `C-c TAB` and choosing `string`. You can then build your regexp using only regexp escaping, and when you're done type `C-c C-w` to copy the fully-escaped string syntax to the kill ring.

Answer (score 3):

Re: cumbersome, it helps to have a look at the documentation of Emacs' regexps:

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-of-Regexps.html

Section 3, "Regexp Backslash", contains the answer to your question which has been pointed out by nhahtdh already. Don't forget that Emacs' regular expression syntax predates the POSIX standard.